# Should android custom view contain any business logic ?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Should a custom android view that extends a View or a ViewGroup object contain any logic different than the one for visualizing the content ? So for example if I create a custom view containing some UI form, should it contain any logic for validation of the input ? Or making a WS call to populate some content in it ?

Comment: I think it's better if you keep the validations in a separate class or something

Answer (score 0):

It may vary from one to another, I would go with separating business logic, so you could have a class that does the job and tells your view what to do.

Imagine it as its some sort of `MVP`

Your `Presenter` which does the business logic and tells the `View` what it should do via a contract(interface).

To give a more clear vision follow simple example below:

```
interface ViewContract {
    fun showErrorMsg()
    fun showSuccessMsg()
}

class View : ViewContract {
    override fun showErrorMsg() {
        TODO("show error")
    }

    override fun showSuccessMsg() {
        TODO("show success")
    }

}

class Presenter(val view: ViewContract) {
    fun validateForm(...some parameters...) {
        if (isNotValid) {// isValid
            view.showErrorMsg()
        } else {
            view.showSuccessMsg()
        }
    }
}
```